# What's the difference between as.integer() and +0L used on booleans?

Tags: r

I saw `+0L` used in an answer to a question and found out that it works well with matrices / data frames / data tables where `as.integer()` would be unable to preserve the initial data classes.

```
> a <- matrix(TRUE, nrow=3, ncol=3)
> a
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
[2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
[3,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
> as.integer(a)
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
> a+0L
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1
```

- Is there other differences between these approaches?
- What are the pros and cons and caveats when using one or the other?

[edit:] lots of wisdom in comments! Apparently there is many different ways to achieve the same result, some of which I had no idea about, so:

- What are the other ways to achieve what `a+0L` does?

Comment: To get the original dimensions, `'dim<-'(as.integer(a), dim(a))`.  If there is `Inf` as one of the elements, `as.integer` coerces it to `NA`, while the `+0L` gives `Inf` value for that element

Comment: Or just `a[] <- as.integer(a)`. Though it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Or, `storage.mode(a) <- "integer"`

Comment: Another way to achieve what `a+0L` does is:

`apply(a, MARGIN = 1, FUN = as.integer)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`x + 0L` is an *element wise* operation on `x`; as such, it often preserves the shape of the data. `as.integer` isn’t: it takes the whole structure – here, a matrix – and converts it into a one-dimensional integer vector.

That said, in the general case I’d strongly suggest using `as.integer` and discourage `+ 0L` as a clever hack (remember: often, clever ≠ good). If you want to preserve the shape of data I suggest using David’s method from the comments, rather than the `+ 0L` hack:

```
a[] = as.integer(a)
```

This uses the normal meaning of `as.integer`, but the result is assigned to *the individual elements of `a`*, rather than `a` itself. In other words, `a`’s shape remains untouched.

Comment: strongly agree.  I wonder how `storage.mode(a) <- "integer"` (as commented above by @James) compares in terms of transparency and efficiency

Comment: I guess `"storage.mode<-"` should be the more formal way to do this since it justs coerces and keeps attributes. `"[<-"`, on the other hand, needs coercions in `as.integer(a)` and when subassigning an "integer" to a, still, "logical" `a`. A benchmark: `m1 = m2 =  matrix(TRUE, 1e4, 1e3); system.time({ m1[] = as.integer(m1) }); system.time({ storage.mode(m2) = "integer" })`

Comment: @alexis_laz I have to admit that I find the `storage.mode<-` method terribly obscure. It essentially does very much the same (`mode<-` would in fact call `as.xyz` on the members, `storage.mode<-` does conceptually the same, but more optimised) as `as.integer`, but in a much less clear way.

Comment: I agree that `"storage.mode<-"` and `as.integer` operate the same on the object (both call `coerceVector`), but, I guess, `"storage.mode<-"` has a more flexible functionality in modifying an existing object:  it preserves attributes and does not do the extra coercions that `"[<-"` does in the present case.

Comment: @alexis_laz -- `a[] <- as.integer(a)` preserves attributes too. (Try `attr(a, "foo")  <- "bar"; attributes(a); a[] <- as.integer(a); attributes(a)` to confirm.) And it's not clear (to me at least) that `storage.mode<-` does fewer coersions. Are you sure that it does?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien : `"[<-"` keeps the attributes in this case; i.e. to use `as.integer` the properties of subassignment are needed. Unless I've missed something serious the coercions in `a[] <- as.integer(a)` are (1) `as.integer(a)` and (2) changing the logical "a" to accept the integer "a" ; see `SubassignTypeFix` in -e.g.- [`VectorAssign`](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/subassign.c)

Comment: @alexis_laz -- OK, I guess I was imagining that in both cases R needs to (1) convert a logical vector to integer and (2) 'overwrite' the logical vector stored in `a` with an integer vector (presumably by pointing to a different area in memory, since the integer vector will be longer). Not sure I can follow what's in VectorAssign, especially since I'm not sure (without digging) which R operation it corresponds to. Is is the code underlying operations of the form `x[]<-...`?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien : Yes, it concerns `"[<-"`. As a reference, see, also, [`do_storage_mode`](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/coerce.c) which seems to just coerce "a" to the wanted `typeof`, while `a[] <- as.integer(a)` coerces "a" in both separate calls (`as.integer` and `"[<-"`). (Sorry for my overloading this answer with comments)

Comment: @alexis_laz This is what comments are for.

Comment: @alexis_laz Aha! So just to be certain I understand, the idea is that `a[]<-as.integer(a)` is processed very much like `a[1,1] <- 1L` would be: in both cases the entire LHS vector is coerced to integer before being subassigned into, right? In other words, `a[]<- as.integer(a)` isn't processed differently than any other "subassignment", even though its effect is to reassign **all** of the values. Very interesting! And thanks for bearing with me to clarify that point!

Comment: Should I try and make a list of all the solutions and background in the original post? Or would someone like to put together a comprehensive answer?

Answer (score 12):

Adding `0L` promotes `a` to integer as described in `?Arithmetic`:

> Logical vectors will be coerced to integer or numeric vectors, FALSE
>   having value zero and TRUE having value one.

As a consequence any arithmetic operation using `a` and the identity element for that operation (but doesn't have to go to numeric at some point, eg `/` and `^`) will work:

```
a+0L
a-0L
a*1L
a%/%1
```

Unary operations will also work, so perhaps the "best" code golf version is:

```
--a
```

This has a parallel with the common trick of using `!!a` to convert a numeric object to logical.

```
identical(a+0L, a-0L, a*1L, a%/%1L, --a)
[1] TRUE
```

Converting back to logical:

```
identical(a, !!--a)
[1] TRUE
```

An alternative, and perhaps clearer, approach is to change the `storage.mode` of `a` directly:

```
storage.mode(a) <- "integer"
a
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1
```

Comment: Ah, the good old systematic approach to knowledge - reveal the underlying principles!

Comment: Why is `+a` missing here?

Answer (score 6):

*(This answer adds no other alternative to the ones already present, but I'm posting just to tidy up comments in this thread.)*

`as.integer`, *by definition*, behaves like `as.vector`, i.e. it strips all attributes ("dim" included) to create an R vector. It won't, just, return the same object with a changed `typeof`. To restore attributes after the coercion, `"dim<-"`, `"names<-"`, `"class<-"` etc. need to be called explicitly or via a function that stores attributes of its arguments (e.g. `"[<-"`). E.g. `"dim<-"(as.integer(a), dim(a))` or `array(as.integer(a), dim(a))` or `a[] <- as.integer(a)`. A benchmark:

```
x = matrix(T, 1e3, 1e3)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark("dim<-"(as.integer(x), dim(x)),
                               array(as.integer(x), dim(x)), 
                               { x[] = as.integer(x) }, times = 25)
#Unit: milliseconds
#                           expr      min       lq   median        uq      max neval
# `dim<-`(as.integer(x), dim(x)) 1.650232 1.691296 2.492748  4.237985  5.67872    25
#   array(as.integer(x), dim(x)) 6.226130 6.638513 8.526779  8.973268 47.50351    25
#    {     x[] = as.integer(x) } 7.822421 8.071243 9.658487 10.408435 11.90798    25
```

In the above, `"dim<-"` justs adds an attribute to the created `as.integer(x)`, `array` allocates a new vector to store the created `as.integer(x)`, and `"[<-"` changes "x" so that it can accept the values of the created `as.integer(x)` and, then, iterates through "x" to insert its new values.

The `"[<-"` method, though, has a disadvantage:

```
x = as.character(1:5)
x
#[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
x[] = as.integer(x)
x
#[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
```

Or:

```
x = 1:5
x
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
x[] = as.logical(x)
x
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

But:

```
x = round(runif(5), 2)
x
#[1] 0.68 0.54 0.02 0.14 0.08
x[] = as.character(x)
x
#[1] "0.68" "0.54" "0.02" "0.14" "0.08"
```

I.e. `"[<-"` won't change the `typeof` of the replaceable object if the `typeof` of replacement object is higher. *Subassignment* (i.e. `"[<-"`) coerces either the object to be replaced *or* the replacing object *or* none depending on their `typeof`s (this is done by [`SubassignTypeFix`](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/subassign.c)). @Josh O'Brien notes the possibility for a difference to exist in the behaviour of `"[<-"` if the indices are missing. To be honest, I could not find a specific treatment in such case, as in, for example [`do_subset_dflt`](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/subset.c) (`"["`) that indirectly handles missingness.

As already mentioned, there is, also, `"storage.mode<-"` to change the `typeof` of an object:

```
"storage.mode<-"(as.character(1:5), "integer")
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
"storage.mode<-"(1:5, "logical")
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
"storage.mode<-"(round(runif(5), 2), "character")
#[1] "0.09" "0.38" "0.98" "0.73" "0.81"

x = matrix(T, 1e3, 1e3)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark("storage.mode<-"(x, "integer"), 
                               "dim<-"(as.integer(x), dim(x)), times = 25)
#Unit: milliseconds
#                           expr      min      lq   median       uq      max neval
# `storage.mode<-`(x, "integer") 1.986055 2.01842 2.147181 2.406096 6.019415    25
# `dim<-`(as.integer(x), dim(x)) 1.984664 2.02016 2.111684 2.613854 6.174973    25
```

Similar in efficiency to `"dim<-"` since they both coerce once and store an attribute.

Binary operations (as mentioned by James and Konrad Rudolph) coerce their arguments to suitable `typeof` and keep attributes ("dim", "names", "class" etc.) depending on rules regarding the two arguments. (Section "Value" in `?Arithmetic`)