# How to convert ordinal date day-month-year format using R

Tags: r, date

I have log files where the date is mentioned in the ordinal date format.

[wikipedia page for ordinal date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date)

i.e 14273 implies 273'rd day of 2014 so 14273 is 30-Sep-2014.

is there a function in R to convert ordinal date (14273) to (30-Sep-2014).

Tried the date package but didn come across a function that would do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `as.Date` with the indicated format:

```
as.Date(sprintf("%05d", 14273), format = "%y%j")
## [1] "2014-09-30"
```

**Notes**

1. For more information see `?strptime` [[link]](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/strptime.html)
2. The `273` part is sometimes referred to as the day of the year (as opposed to the day of the month) or the day number or the julian day relative to the beginning of the year.
3. If the input were a character string of the form `yyjjj` (rather than numeric) then `as.Date(x, format = "%y%j")` will do.

**Update**  Have updated to also handle years with one digit as per comments.

Comment: This does not seem to work for: as.Date(paste(07273), format = "%y%j")

Comment: Nice, but would like to know how this works, i read the help document in R, didn understand the %j in the code should be for no. of days since 1st jan 2014 is there a specific term for that (JDN) ?

Comment: @RuthgerRighart I think it is a padding issue `as.Date(sprintf('%05d', 7273), format='%y%j')` or `formatC(07273, width=5, flag='0')`

Comment: @akrun nice catch, I think this should be the actual answer.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I like the concise approach of `paste`, though `formatC` might be a bit faster according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447014/the-fastest-way-to-convert-numeric-to-character-in-r  (and perhaps more general)

Comment: @vinay, have added some notes.

Answer (score 2):

Data example

```
x<-as.character(c("14273", "09001", "07031", "01033"))
```

Data conversion

```
x1<-substr(x, start=0, stop=2)
x2<-substr(x, start=3, stop=5)
x3<-format(strptime(x2, format="%j"), format="%m-%d")

date<-as.Date(paste(x3, x1, sep="-"), format="%m-%d-%y")
```

Comment: I think this is just overcomplicating Gabors solution. There is no need in all of this if you can just use `%j`...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lubridate` package as follows:

```
>library(lubridate)

# Create a template date object
>date <- as.POSIXlt("2009-02-10")

# Update the date using 
> update(date, year=2014, yday=273)
[1] "2014-09-30 JST"
```