# Change Numeric Variables to be Categorical in R

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion, numeric, categorical-data

Short and sweet here...

I have ZIP codes in the dataframe I am analyzing in R.

R is reading them as numeric variables. How can I have R read these ZIP codes (e.g., 20001) as a **categorical** variable.

Comment: `data$ZIP <- as.character(data$ZIP)` or `data$ZIP <- as.factor(data$ZIP)`, depending on the variable type you prefer to work with

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The fastest way to convert numeric to character in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447014/the-fastest-way-to-convert-numeric-to-character-in-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Just making my comment an answer*)

You can use

```
data$ZIP <- as.character(data$ZIP)
```

or

```
data$ZIP <- as.factor(data$ZIP)
```

depending on the variable type you prefer to work with.