# Is there an alternative to sign() that returns integer values?

Tags: r

A sign function only needs to return values -1, 0 or 1, all of which are easily represented as integers, yet `sign()` returns them as doubles/numerics.

```
> str(sign(1))
 num 1
> str(sign(1L))
 num 1
> str(sign(matrix(rnorm(16),4)))
 num [1:4, 1:4] 1 -1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1 ...
```

My guess is this was done because `NaN` is stored as a double. But it would be very convenient for me if there were a function as lightweight as `sign()` that did the same thing but returned integer values (I don't care what it does with `NaN` inputs).

I know about `as.integer()` but it returns matrices as vectors, which is inconvenient. `function(x) (x>0)-(x<0)` works but requires more memory (this matters for big matrices).

Is there a version of `sign()` that returns integers? If not, how can I most easily make one?

Comment: Use `"dim<-"(as.integer(sign(x)), dim(x))`, where `x` is your matrix

Comment: Helpful post: [What's the difference between as.integer() and +0L used on booleans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412049/whats-the-difference-between-as-integer-and-0l-used-on-booleans)

Comment: (x > 0) - (x < 0) only uses temporary memory. If that is too large it is hard to belive you ca do any meaningful calculations at all.

Answer (score 1):

Simple helper-function:

```r
sign.int <- function(x) { y <- sign(x); structure(as.integer(y), .Dim = dim(x)); }

set.seed(42)
str(sign(matrix(rnorm(16),4)))
#  num [1:4, 1:4] 1 -1 1 1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 ...
set.seed(42)
str(sign.int(matrix(rnorm(16),4)))
#  int [1:4, 1:4] 1 -1 1 1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 ...
```

---

Comparison with @G.Grothendieck's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64271596/3358272), which is much faster:

```r
ggrothendieck <- function(m) (m>0)-(m<0)
bench::mark(sign.int(m), ggrothendieck(m))
# # A tibble: 2 x 13
#   expression          min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result    memory     time    gc      
#   <bch:expr>       <bch:> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>    <list>     <list>  <list>  
# 1 sign.int(m)       6.6us  11.9us    67006.        0B        0 10000     0    149.2ms <int[,4]~ <Rprofmem~ <bch:t~ <tibble~
# 2 ggrothendieck(m)  1.9us   2.3us   255343.        0B        0 10000     0     39.2ms <int[,4]~ <Rprofmem~ <bch:t~ <tibble~
identical(sign.int(m), ggrothendieck(m))
# [1] TRUE
```

... and since that function appears much simpler (and more elegant in many ways), I suggest that's the better function.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck you should undelete your answer, it's better.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The (x>0) - (x<0) function was actually in my original post. It works very nicely and it's my current solution but it is a little slower than sign().

Comment: `sign` is a primitive function, there's very little you can do to achieve that level. You could code something in `Rcpp` ...